# Generate a 'Guru Meditation Error' on an Amiga

Tags: amiga

Can anyone post some source code that, when compiled (if necessary) and run, will produce a 'Guru Meditation Error' on an Amiga.

Assembler, C or ARexx will do.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Steve, late comment but you might be interested in our RetroComputing SE proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441/retrocomputing?referrer=jua8Sp9gEDXnou2V41ekZw2

Comment: Thanks Lacey =- I've signed up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `Alert()` function of the `exec.library`: http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Includes_and_Autodocs_3._guide/node01E3.html

For instance (in C):

```c
#include <exec/execbase.h>
#include <exec/alerts.h>

#include <clib/exec_protos.h>

void main(void) {
    Alert(ACPU_InstErr); /* or use 0x80000004 if you don't have alerts.h */

    /* might not return if it was a dead end (non-recoverable) alert */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A good old division by zero can do the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  printf("%d", 1/0);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Guys - this was in response to something on 'Code Golf' about generation weird/amusing errors. I thought a 'Guru Meditation' would count...

Comment: This isn't the most direct way to invoke a Guru, and a recent compiler might be reluctant with the explicit division by zero :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the `divide by zero` method is the most direct one to invoke a Guru Mediation.
I tried on the actual AmigaOS3.1 and the `divide by zero` error is caught by the OS before it ends up in the Guru we love :)

[image]

To be honest, I was even surprised that SAS/C would accept to compile this code.
GCC is less tolerant:

```bash
astrofra@ubuntu: ~$ gcc main.c
main.c:3:17: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
   printf("%d", 1/0);
```

The AmigaOS `Alert()` function is indeed recommended. I used it extensively at debugging stage when working on [Athanor 2](http://hol.abime.net/6549).